# We consider a fluid which rotates around the $z-$ axis with constant angular speed $w$

Tags: vector-analysis

I have the following exercise in my notes and I need some explanations.

We consider a fluid which rotates around the $z-$ axis with constant angular speed $w$

[image]

$$\overrightarrow{r}=x \hat{\imath}+y \hat{\jmath}$$

$$\overrightarrow{\theta}=-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath}$$

$$\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{r}(-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath})$$

$$\overrightarrow{v}=wr(\frac{-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath}}{r})$$

$$\overrightarrow{v}=w(-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath})$$

---

Which is the general formula of $v$ that we have used?

Isn't it $wr$ as it is shown at the picture?

Comment: $v = \omega \times r$

Comment: And what is the vector $\overrightarrow{\theta}$?

Comment: It seems to be a tangential vector at position $\overrightarrow{r}$.

Comment: I got stuck right now... :/ Isn't the tangential vector at position $\overrightarrow{r}$ equal to the derivative of $r$? Or is this only when it is in the form $r(t)$?

Comment: The tangential vector $\overrightarrow{\theta}$ is given by

$\frac{d \overrightarrow{r}}{d\theta}= \frac{d}{d\theta}[rcos(\theta)\overrightarrow{i}+rsin(\theta)\overrightarrow{j}]=[-rsin(\theta)\overrightarrow{i}+rcos(\theta)\overrightarrow{j}]=-y \overrightarrow{i}+x\overrightarrow{j}$

Comment: @RRL So $\overrightarrow{\theta}=\frac{d \overrightarrow{r}}{d \theta}=-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath}$... To clarify something.. $\overrightarrow{\theta}$ has nothing to do with $\theta$ you used, right? We could also name the variable $\theta$ in an other way, couldn't we?

Comment: @Mary Star: Yes - I am using $r$ and $\theta$ as polar coordinates (see posted answer). The vector theta is a vector in the tangential direction in a new basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ denote the rectangular coordinates of a point and $(r,\theta)$ the corresponding polar coordinates where $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta).  $ The position vector of a fluid particle located at $(x(t),y(t))$ at time $t$ is

$$\overrightarrow{r}(t)= x(t)\overrightarrow{i}+y(t)\overrightarrow{j}=r(t)[\cos(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{i}+\sin(\theta)(t)\overrightarrow{j}].$$

The velocity of this particle is

$$\overrightarrow{v}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\overrightarrow{r}(t)= r'(t)[\cos(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{i}+\sin(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{j}]+r(t)\theta'(t)[-\sin(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{i}+\cos(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{j}]$$

In a rigid body rotation with angular speed $w$, we have

$$r'(t)=0, \\\ \theta'(t) = w,$$

so

$$r(t)=r=const, \\\ \theta(t) = wt +\theta_0,$$

Hence,

$$\overrightarrow{v}(t)= rw[-\sin(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{i}+\cos(\theta(t))\overrightarrow{j}]= w[-y(t)\overrightarrow{i}+x(t)\overrightarrow{j}]$$

The magnitude of the velocity (speed) is therefore $rw$.

Comment: Could you explain me why in a rigid body rotation with angular speed $w$, we have $$r'(t)=0 \text{ and } \theta '(t)=w$$
$$$$
I have a question at the way it is solved in my first post:
$\overrightarrow{\theta}$ is the tangential vector. What is then $\hat{\theta}$? Is it the unit tangential vector? Isn't the formula of the unit tangential vector: $\hat{\theta}=\frac{\theta}{|\theta|}$?

Comment: @Mary Star:  You are correct -- $\hat{\theta}$ as defined above is the unit tangential vector and is given equivalently as $\overrightarrow{\theta}/ \ |\overrightarrow{\theta}|$. The second basis vector would be the radial vector. In a rigid rotation, there is a restriction on how the fluid deforms.  This is just the kinematic definition. In the Lagrangian framework, a fluid particle has no radial velocity component and a constant tangential component - so the time derivatives of $r$ and $\theta$ above are $0$ and a constant $w$ respectively.

Comment: Ok...Since it is $$\hat{\theta}=\frac{\overrightarrow{\theta}}{|\overrightarrow{\theta}|}$$ how do we get the relation $$\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{r}(-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath})$$ ?? Is $$|\overrightarrow{\theta}|=r$$??

Comment: @Mary Star: Yes because the norm of $\overrightarrow{\theta}$ is $\sqrt{(-y)^2+x^2} = r$.  In my post I tried to help clarify with alternative perspective based on the kinematics of a fluid particle. As mentioned in an earlier comment the velocity is also given by the cross product of the angular velocity vector (which points in the z direction) and the position vector -- this leads to the same result. My derivation simply shows why the velocity has this form if the particles are constrained to move on circular paths -- which is the case in rigid rotation.

Comment: Ok!!! I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)